# VB.NET making private variables global

Tags: vb.net, global, private

i have some functions like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Dim act_url As String = WebBrowser1.Url.ToString
MsgBox (act_url)
...
...
End Sub
```

now i want to take the content of act_url to another functions but how can i change it to a global Variable?

Comment: You don't "change it to a global variable".  You can expose it via a public property, a public shared property, pass it to the method, etc.  Can you provide a more complete (but still minimal) example of how you're calling this method?  Simply making everything public and shared isn't generally a good idea, how you arrange your classes and members and pass around your values depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Move it outside the `Button1_Click` method to make it a so called "Class level variable". Read more about [**access levels**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76453kax.aspx) and [**scopes**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare

```
Dim act_url As String=""
```

in your form global declaration section and use this variable anywhere you need, Once it gets value you can access it anywhere in your current form.

if you want to access it in other forms, add a property as act_url in a class and use it in the entire project.

Comment: _if you want to access it in other forms_ > Alternatively, You could declare the variable in a module(If you use) and use it accordingly!

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class Form1

    Private _var As String

    Public Sub Load()
        Dim _anotherVar As String

        _var = "Load"

    End Sub

    Public Sub Save()
        _var = "Save"

    End Sub

End Class
```

Looking at the above code the variable `_var` can be accessed in both the `Load` and `Save` method whilst the variable `_anotherVar` can only be accessed in the `Load` method.

So in your case you need to replace the variable `_var` with your variable and that will allow it to be accessed at any point in your class.